# XML Parsing with Pig using Piggybank

Tags: xml, regex, apache-pig

I am about to load an XML for processing in Pig and have succeeded to some extent. Now wile processing with single line XML tags like below, the provided regex doesn't work.

here is my input data

[image: Input Data]

here is my PigScript

[image: PigScript]

Can you please let me know what's wrong with the regex?

Thanks,
Kalai

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. [Pig 0.3.0 has an XPath class](https://apache.googlesource.com/pig/+/b609216befda834cc57763ff28a96caf0aafa530), discussed in [PIG-3619](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3619).

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you. I am using pig v0.12.0 and using the piggybank at https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank , but while using XPath i am facing the following error

"ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve XPath using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]".

Can you please help me on this.?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, sorry. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789121/how-to-use-jar-in-a-pig-file

Answer (score 0):

The below regex works for me.

b= foreach a generate REGEX_EXTRACT(x,'Id="(?[^"]+)"',1),REGEX_EXTRACT(x,'UserId="(?[^"]+)"',1),REGEX_EXTRACT(x,'Name="(?[^"]+)"',1),REGEX_EXTRACT(x,'Date="(?[^"]+)"',1);

dump b;

Here is the output.

(1815,829,Student,2014-01-18T16:02:02.837)

(1816,401,Commentator,2014-01-18T17:07:19.713)

Thanks,

Kalai